# In data frame, remove all repeat value from col2 and col3 by matching col1 id of row is not matter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the data frame, there is some repeat value in given specific columns
So, I want to remove all repeat values

For example,

In col3 if anything available in col2 and col1 then it  remove from col3.
Same now for col2, if any value from col2 is available in col1 then remove from col2

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5

1    12        1    6    
2    1    9    1    0
3         1    2
4    9    11   3    10 
5    6         4
6    1    3    5
```

Output

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5

1    12        1    6    
2              1    0
3              2
4    9    11   3    10 
5              4
6              5
```

col4 and col5 remain same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
col1= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
col2= [12,1,None,9,6,1]
col3= [None,9,1,11,None,3]
col4= [1,1,2,3,4,5]
col5= [6,0,None,10,None,None]

import pandas as pd
# make df from col1 to col5
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':col1, 'col2':col2, 'col3':col3, 'col4':col4, 'col5':col5})

# iterate over columns
for col in df.columns:
    # remove values that are in previous columns
    for prev_col in df.columns[:df.columns.get_loc(col)]:
        df[col] = df[col].where(~df[col].isin(df[prev_col]), None)
# OUTPUT
#    col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
# 0     1  12.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
# 1     2   NaN   NaN   NaN   0.0
# 2     3   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
# 3     4   9.0  11.0   NaN  10.0
# 4     5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
# 5     6   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: can you please help me for it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74614053/in-dataframe-merge-row-by-matching-multiple-id-but-condition-is-different-for?noredirect=1#comment131703368_74614053

@sudhakar

Answer (score 0):

Using `zip` and the reversed column list in a loop:

```
cols = list(df)[::-1]

for c, prev_c in zip(cols, cols[1:]):
    df.loc[df[c].isin(df[prev_c]), c] = float('nan')
```

output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0     1  12.0   NaN   NaN   6.0
1     2   NaN   NaN   NaN   0.0
2     3   NaN   NaN   2.0   NaN
3     4   9.0  11.0   NaN  10.0
4     5   NaN   NaN   4.0   NaN
5     6   NaN   3.0   5.0   NaN
```

Comment: can you please help me for it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74614053/in-dataframe-merge-row-by-matching-multiple-id-but-condition-is-different-for?noredirect=1#comment131703368_74614053

@mozway

Comment: @hardikramani please read the duplicate link and edit your question with your attempt and what eventually failed